# replacement with multiples single and multiple quotes with a .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping

I would like to replace
`server = "IPHONEDEROMAIN"` with `server = "test"`.
I have used the following command:

```
powershell -Command "(gc connexion.py) -replace 'server = ""IPHONEDEROMAIN""', 'server = ""test""' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.py"
```

The double double quotes are supposed to escape the double quote (https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm) and it ... kinda works, only kinda works. Because I have the following output:

```
server = test"
```

And I'm very confused. Usually it either works or doesn't. Here he does but only for half of it. Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: Double-doubling the trailing quotes before `'` seems to work from cmd (I have no idea why): `powershell -Command "(gc connexion.py) -replace 'server = ""IPHONEDEROMAIN""""', 'server = ""test""""' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.py"`

Comment: This is how I would write your command: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'connexion.py') -Replace 'server = \"IPHONEDEROMAIN\"', 'server = \"test\"' | Out-File -Encoding ASCII 'myFile.py'"```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it worked, it is frankly really weird though

Comment: @Compo What do "-NoLogo -NoProfile" do? your solution worked too but i don't know why i tried earlier and it didn't. I may have done something wrong, main thing is, your solution does work too.

Comment: @Compo actually your solution sometimes doesn't work e.g. if i want to replace "IPHONEDEROMAIN" with test" (i voluntarily just want one quote at the end and no quote in front of test for example) (powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(gc connexion.py) -replace 'server = \"IPHONEDEROMAIN\"', 'server = test\"' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.py")

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows, if you really wanted an imbalanced quoted string, _(I cannot understand why)_, then I'd offer the following alternative, `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'connexion.py') -Replace 'server = \"IPHONEDEROMAIN\"', 'server = test""' | Out-File -Encoding ASCII 'myFile.py'"` or even `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content 'connexion.py') -Replace 'server = ""IPHONEDEROMAIN""', 'server = test""' | Out-File -Encoding ASCII 'myFile.py'"`.

Comment: I was just trying things out. I don't actually need it. I'm just now VERY curious as to WHY this all works like that??? Do you have any explanation?